# how to search data in mysql using like operator on date time column

Tags: mysql

I am creating MySQL query where I need to find data from created_by column (having datetime datatype) using like operator.

I have developed following query:

```
SELECT `order_id`,`order_no`,`name`,`email`,`created_at` FROM orders WHERE
DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')=DATE_FORMAT('2021-02-23 17:37:28','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```

but I want to search data with like operator
for example

1. if I pass created_at date like '2021-02' then it should give me all the result related to this.
2. if I pass created_at date like '2021-02-23 17:' then it should give me all the result related to this.
3. if I pass created_at date like '2021-' then it should give me all the result related to this.
4. if I pass created_at date like '2021-' then it should give me all the result related to this.
   and so many combination like that.

**I have tried this query and it returning expected result**

```
*SELECT `order_id`,`order_no`,`name`,`email`,`created_at` FROM orders WHERE
created_at LIKE '2021-02-23 17:37:28'*
```

*output:*

[image]

**but if I tried this query I unable to get expected result it returning 0 rows**

```
SELECT `order_id`,`order_no`,`name`,`email`,`created_at` FROM orders WHERE
created_at LIKE '2021-02-23 17:37:'
```

*output:*

[image]

please find bellow table script to regenerate issue.
(you can put any available date from provided data in created_by column)

```
create table `orders` (
    `order_id` int (11),
    `order_no` varchar (300),
    `sub_order_no` varchar (300),
    `name` varchar (300),
    `email` varchar (300),
    `created_at` datetime 
); 
insert into `orders` (`order_id`, `order_no`, `sub_order_no`, `name`, `email`, `created_by`) values('1','202102','964','23038','pqr@gmail.com','2021-02-23 17:37:28');
insert into `orders` (`order_id`, `order_no`, `sub_order_no`, `name`, `email`, `created_by`) values('2','202102','965','22166638','abc@gmail.com','2021-02-23 17:37:28');
insert into `orders` (`order_id`, `order_no`, `sub_order_no`, `name`, `email`, `created_by`) values('3','202133','966','2202166638','def@gmail.com','2021-02-23 17:37:28');
insert into `orders` (`order_id`, `order_no`, `sub_order_no`, `name`, `email`, `created_by`) values('4','202044','967','2302166638','jkl@gmail.com','2021-02-23 17:37:28');
insert into `orders` (`order_id`, `order_no`, `sub_order_no`, `name`, `email`, `created_by`) values('5','202105','968','2302166638','lmn@gmail.com','2021-02-23 17:37:28');
```

as my knowledge in MySQL is limited so guys your help will be apricated to improve myself, thank you !!

Comment: You should do these as datetime range searches - i.e. `created_at >= x and created_at < y` - not by running functions against `created_at` or casting it to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql recognizes dates, if you write the correct format

So you can use a simple =

LIKE is only for strings

You have a lot if [functions][1] for date and time, i am sure yyou find the correct to get your orders

> ```
> create table `orders` (
>     `order_id` int (11),
>     `order_no` varchar (300),
>     `sub_order_no` varchar (300),
>     `name` varchar (300),
>     `email` varchar (300),
>     `created_at` datetime 
> ); 
> insert into `orders` (`order_id`, `order_no`, `sub_order_no`, `name`, `email`, `created_at`) values('1','202102','964','23038','pqr@gmail.com','2021-02-23 17:37:28');
> insert into `orders` (`order_id`, `order_no`, `sub_order_no`, `name`, `email`, `created_at`) values('2','202102','965','22166638','abc@gmail.com','2021-02-23 17:37:28');
> insert into `orders` (`order_id`, `order_no`, `sub_order_no`, `name`, `email`, `created_at`) values('3','202133','966','2202166638','def@gmail.com','2021-02-23 17:37:28');
> insert into `orders` (`order_id`, `order_no`, `sub_order_no`, `name`, `email`, `created_at`) values('4','202044','967','2302166638','jkl@gmail.com','2021-02-23 17:37:28');
> insert into `orders` (`order_id`, `order_no`, `sub_order_no`, `name`, `email`, `created_at`) values('5','202105','968','2302166638','lmn@gmail.com','2021-02-23 17:37:28');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `order_id`,`order_no`,`name`,`email`,`created_at` FROM orders WHERE
> created_at ='2021-02-23 17:37:28'
> ```

> ```
> order_id | order_no | name       | email         | created_at         
> -------: | :------- | :--------- | :------------ | :------------------
>        1 | 202102   | 23038      | pqr@gmail.com | 2021-02-23 17:37:28
>        2 | 202102   | 22166638   | abc@gmail.com | 2021-02-23 17:37:28
>        3 | 202133   | 2202166638 | def@gmail.com | 2021-02-23 17:37:28
>        4 | 202044   | 2302166638 | jkl@gmail.com | 2021-02-23 17:37:28
>        5 | 202105   | 2302166638 | lmn@gmail.com | 2021-02-23 17:37:28
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `order_id`,`order_no`,`name`,`email`,`created_at` FROM orders WHERE
> DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m') ='2021-02'
> ```
>
> ```
> order_id | order_no | name       | email         | created_at         
> -------: | :------- | :--------- | :------------ | :------------------
>        1 | 202102   | 23038      | pqr@gmail.com | 2021-02-23 17:37:28
>        2 | 202102   | 22166638   | abc@gmail.com | 2021-02-23 17:37:28
>        3 | 202133   | 2202166638 | def@gmail.com | 2021-02-23 17:37:28
>        4 | 202044   | 2302166638 | jkl@gmail.com | 2021-02-23 17:37:28
>        5 | 202105   | 2302166638 | lmn@gmail.com | 2021-02-23 17:37:28
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6c2310e73f6e3ce925d5fde50d4e89fc)*

Comment: but how to solve if i tried this 1)if I pass created_at date like '2021-02' then it should give me all the result related to this.
if I pass created_at date like '2021-02-23 17:' then it should give me all the result related to this.
if I pass created_at date like '2021-' then it should give me all the result related to this.
if I pass created_at date like '2021-' then it should give me all the result related to this. and so many combination like that.

Comment: You write `YEAR(create_at)` = 2021 or see my added example at the end